# How to run a bash script from a web server using apache?

Tags: html, linux, apache

How can I execute a file by using web server like apache in the local network by hosting a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/howto/cgi.html) or [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).
If you transmit arguments from your webpage to your script, be sure to sanitize inputs to prevent code injection.